# Passing a pointer to a struct as a function argument

Tags: c, pointers, struct, pass-by-reference

I'm trying to pass a pointer to a struct over to a separate function. But when I go to compile, I get `warning: passing argument 1 of 'build_network_state' from incompatible pointer type`

This is in a helper function the compiles into my program:

```
typedef struct router {
    int num;
    char label[64];
    Topology *topology;
} Router;
```

This is from the .c file:

```
void build_network_state(Router *ptr) {

    fprintf(stdout, "Hello from router %s\n", ptr->label);
}

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {

    Router* this_router = malloc(sizeof(Router));

    ...

    fprintf(stdout, "test: %s\n", this_router->label); // output looks fine if I comment the next line
    build_network_state(&this_router);
}
```

Comment: @chux No, not quite. That's because `this_router` is already of type `Router *`. There's no need for the addressof operator.

Comment: @H2CO3 Congrats on 100K

Comment: @chux No problem. Leaving my comment here anyway as an information to OP.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
build_network_state(&this_router);
```

should be

```
build_network_state(this_router);
```

because `this_router`is already of type `Router *`. (But `&this_router` is of type `Router  **`)

And

```
Router* this_router = malloc(sizeof(Router));
```

should be

```
Router* this_router = malloc(sizeof *this_router);
```

You want to allocate the size of the structure object, not the size of the pointer to the structure object.

Comment: You're welcome. +1 for explaining the problem anyway.

Comment: @ouah Thank you! :) It took quite a long time. :P

Comment: Yes, I knew that this question would have the C experts racing to their keyboards to see who could answer it first! Thanks again!

Answer (score 1):

`this_router` is already a pointer to a router struct.  You don't need to pass an address to it to `build_network_state`.

```
build_network_state(this_router);
```